# How can I get the volume of the sound from music object in sfml?

Tags: c++, audio, sfml

I'm trying to write a program in c++ and I need to get the peak volume of a lot of small chunks of a 2h long audio, apparently this can be done in sfml by just using audioBuffer and getting the maximum value of the array, but this is a music object because it's a very large file, how can I turn a music object into a sound object or even better, can I get the peak volume just from the music object (the more efficient, the better). Also any other somewhat simple solution for this problem is welcome.

Comment: it won't get better than "this can be done in sfml by just using audioBuffer and getting the maximum value of the array"

Comment: But then the question would be how do I extract this chunks from the music object into audioBuffer objects whose volume I can then calculate. I can't find any way to do that